# double if condition in a Python for loop

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop

I am working on a python [exercise](http://codingbat.com/prob/p164876) that asks:

```
# Return True if the string "cat" and "dog" appear the same number of
# times in the given string. 
# cat_dog('catdog') → True
# cat_dog('catcat') → False
# cat_dog('1cat1cadodog') → True
```

This is my current code:

```
def cat_dog(str):
   c=0
   d=0
   for i in range(len(str)-2):
     if str[i:i+3]=="cat":
       c=+1
     if str[i:i+3]=="dog":
       d=+1
   return (c-d)==0.0
```

I look at it and I think it should work but it failed some of the tests, which suggest to me I am not understanding something in how Python logic works. Any explanation as to why my solution is not working would be great. These are all the test results:

```
cat_dog('catdog') → True            True          OK        
cat_dog('catcat') → False           False         OK        
cat_dog('1cat1cadodog') → True      True          OK        
cat_dog('catxxdogxxxdog') → False   True          X     
cat_dog('catxdogxdogxcat') → True   True          OK            
cat_dog('catxdogxdogxca') → False   True          X  
cat_dog('dogdogcat') → False        True          X
cat_dog('dogdogcat') → False        True          OK        
cat_dog('dog') → False              False         OK        
cat_dog('cat') → False              False         OK        
cat_dog('ca') → True                True          OK        
cat_dog('c') → True                 True          OK        
cat_dog('') → True                  True          OK
```

Comment: I think you mean `c += 1` and `d += 1` instead of `c=+1` and `d=+1`

Comment: of course, a simple typo, as clear from gnibbler's answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should have

`c += 1` instead of `c = +1`

and

`d += 1` instead of `d = +1`

Answer (score 5):

A simpler way to solve this problem would be to use built-in string functions, like this:

```
def cat_dog(s):
    return s.count('cat') == s.count('dog')
```

Comment: how is the code making the assumption that they appear next to one another?

Comment: I was going to ask the same

Answer (score 3):

Here is a one-liner for your program;

```
cat_dog=lambda str1: str1.count("cat")==str1.count("dog")
print (cat_dog("catcat"))
```

It will return `True` if counts are equal, else returning `False`. But if this confused you, here long one.

```
def cat_dog(str1):
    c="cat"
    d="dog"
    a=str1.count(c)
    b=str1.count(d)
    if a==b:
        return True
    return False
print (cat_dog('catcat'))
```

Here is a better method. `count` is very usefull for your program. Less codes, because [**readability**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) counts.

```
print (cat_dog('catcat')) -False
print (cat_dog('catdog')) -True
```